# How to block localhost ip on spicific webpage?

Tags: php, ip

For example:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1-127.0.0.9") die();
```

This works for me with remote ips only.

Comment: use ip2long in your condition

Answer (score -1):

I did some research on the internet and I think that
[here is your answer.](https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/blocking-multiple-ip-addresses-php)